# magento2 - undefined index title in User role page

Tags: magento2

Why do I get this when I try to create a new User role in Magento2:

> Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined index: title in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2x_2\app\code\Magento\Integration\Helper\Data.php on line 24

1. I have all the titles defined in my custom xml file.
2. var/ cache, generation cleared.
3. run setup upgrade.

Help required!

Answer (score 2):

Go to your freshly created modules (some modules which you created last or before), open `app/code/Name_Space/Module_Name/etc/acl.xml`

put 'title tag' like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
<acl>
    <resources>
        <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores">
                <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores_settings">
                    <resource id="Magento_Config::config">
                        <resource id="Namespace_Modulename::config_namespace_modulename" title="Put Here the Title"/>
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</acl>
</config>
```

This worked for me. Hope this would work for you also.
All the best !

Comment: I'm getting the same issue but with a slightly different error message. If my error message is saying /vendor/magento/module-user/ then does that mean that there should be the acl.xml file located at the /vendor/magento/module-user/etc folder?

Comment: For me, i was in mid of creating a module with missing title in its acl, and this error was in order panel, however my module was not related to order anyways

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that one of your modules doesn't have a title defined in the acl.xml file.  The easiest way to fix this is to update in `src/vendor/magento/module-integration/Helper/Data.php` to have:

```
$item['data'] = isset($resource['title']) ? $resource['title'] : '';
```

This will enable the UI to load but for one or many of the modules will have a blank space next to the folder.  You then need to let the module developer know to fix the issue, but as a short term fix just add a title attribute to the `acl.xml` for the module yourself.